# Condensing a sparse confusion matrix for display

Tags: data-visualization, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to display the confusion matrices for various NLP components and a few of them, most notably the part of speech tagger, have rather sparse confusion matrices. So far I've only been able to find resources on how to store a sparse matrix, which isn't particularly helpful since I'm already storing it in a dense way. So given that I want to display the matrices in a table format, what are some methods I can use to achieve a more dense (visual) representation of the data?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a table, and maybe an example of the context it would appear in?

Comment: Do you mean the type of condensed table that I'm looking for or a general table of confusion matrix results? I can really only provide an example of the latter.

Comment: The latter. Is it just a multi-class classification matrix? I'm only familiar with binary confusion matrices

Comment: Yeah, multi-class. For instance, the columns would be the predicted POS tags, the rows the actual POS tags and the values the counts of each combination.